# Plot 3D in R with customization?

Tags: r, plot

I would like to have something like below.I am not expert in R, but I was wondering if someone can give me tips which function could help me with that.  I tried to use wireframe and it was ended by the figure below.
I have two problems:

- I need to have specific range for x, y, and z. I tried to use
  xlim,ylim, and zlim within wireframe as below, but didn't give me the
  right answer.
- I need only lines for x, y and z axis. I want them to have x as straight line with 180 degree, and y with 90, and z as 45 or something in between. I also don't want the full box frame, when I tried to use par.box = c(col = "transparent") in wireframe , it removes all frames including the axes (x,y, and z). I tried to play a little bit with screen parameters, but still didn't help me with right way

[image: below]

```
 wireframe(temp, 
        scales = list(arrows = FALSE,col="black", font=10, tck=0.5),
        #xlim = 2^seq(0,6),
        panel.aspect = 0.7, zoom = 1, lwd = 0.01,
        #ylim = seq(1,10,1),
        #zlim = seq(10000,80000,10000),
        drape = TRUE, colorkey = TRUE,
        xlab ="X" , ylab ="Y", zlab ="Z",
        #screen = list(z = 30, y= 90, x=180),
        #par.box = c(col = "transparent"),
  )
```